# How can I apply for a UK visa to attend a conference

Tags: visas, uk

I am supposed to attend a five day entrepreneurship conference in the UK in November and I am stuck on how to apply for a visa and what are the visa requirements.

Comment: Depending on your citizenship, you may not need a visa at all.

Answer (score 5):

I can't find the canonical question and answer for this, but to find out what Visa you need, what supporting documents are required and how to apply, a good place to start is

- https://www.gov.uk/apply-uk-visa
- https://www.gov.uk/standard-visitor-visa/overview

The latter says

> You can apply for a Standard Visitor visa if you want to visit the UK for business-related activities, eg:
>
> - you’re coming to the UK for a conference, meeting or training
> - ...

---

Related questions

- [UK visa type to attend conference and training in London](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/66470/13639)
- [UK visa application - what visa type to select for a conference?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/71005/13639)
- [Visa type for Scotland to attend Conference from India](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/100124/13639)
- [Enquiry for visa requirement](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/61192/13639)
- [List of other questions about UK visa for attending a conference](https://travel.stackexchange.com/search?q=uk+conference+visa+is%3Aq)

Please make a careful note of the last item. This website contains a treasure-trove of information  that you can easily search and benefit from **before, or instead of, asking a new question**.